# IBM Worklight OutOfSyncException

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server, websphere-liberty

Environment:

1. IBM Worklight 6.2.0.0 Consumer Edition
2. Liberty 8.5.5.1
3. IBM DB2
4. Windows 2008 Server
5. iPhone 5 - IOS 7
6. Adapter based authentication

2 nodes of Worklight Server points a single DB2 Instance.

Direct update is prompted frequently when I try to login. But I have an updated build running on my device.

Even if I proceed with the update, device build rolled back to previous build.

After sometime device prompts to update, this time new build has been updated.

I got the following as logs.

```
[ERROR   ] RuntimeMBeanCallable.call() exception
java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
[err] java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
[err]   at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy137.deleteApplication(Unknown Source)
[err]   at com.ibm.worklight.admin.actions.ApplicationDeletionTransaction.prepareMBean(ApplicationDeletionTransaction.java:160)
[err]   at com.ibm.worklight.admin.actions.util.RuntimeMBeanWorkerThreadCaller$RuntimeMBeanCallable.call(RuntimeMBeanWorkerThreadCaller.java:75)
[err]   at com.ibm.worklight.admin.actions.util.RuntimeMBeanWorkerThreadCaller.callSynchronously(RuntimeMBeanWorkerThreadCaller.java:182)
[err]   at com.ibm.worklight.admin.actions.util.RuntimeMBeanPoolCaller.callRuntimeMBeans(RuntimeMBeanPoolCaller.java:91)
[err]   at com.ibm.worklight.admin.actions.BaseTransaction.prepare(BaseTransaction.java:364)
[err]   at com.ibm.worklight.admin.actions.BaseTransaction.internalRun(BaseTransaction.java:307)
[err]   at com.ibm.worklight.admin.actions.BaseTransaction.run(BaseTransaction.java:227)
[err]   at com.ibm.worklight.admin.services.ApplicationService.deleteApplication(ApplicationService.java:521)

.
.
.
.
.
.

[err]   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
[err]   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.run(AbstractHandlersChain.java:52)
[err]   at org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor.handleRequestWithoutFaultBarrier(RequestProcessor.java:207)
[err]   at org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor.handleRequest(RequestProcessor.java:154)
[err]   at org.apache.wink.server.internal.servlet.RestServlet.service(RestServlet.java:133)
[err]   at com.ibm.worklight.admin.services.RestServlet.service(RestServlet.java:39)
[err]   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
[err]   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1239)
[err]   at [internal classes]
[err] Caused by: java.io.IOException: CWWKX0204E: Unable to parse Throwable from server error stream.
[err]   at com.ibm.ws.jmx.connector.client.rest.internal.RESTMBeanServerConnection.getServerThrowable(RESTMBeanServerConnection.java:1712)
[err]   at [internal classes]
[err]   ... 83 more
[err] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.worklight.twopc.exceptions.OutOfSyncException
[err]   at com.ibm.ws.kernel.internal.classloader.JarFileClassLoader.findClass(JarFileClassLoader.java:96)
[err]   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
[err]   at com.ibm.ws.kernel.internal.classloader.BootstrapChildFirstJarClassloader.loadClass(BootstrapChildFirstJarClassloader.java:56)
[err]   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
[err]   at com.ibm.ws.serialization.DeserializationObjectInputStream.loadClass(DeserializationObjectInputStream.java:57)
[err]   at [internal classes]
[err]   ... 87 more
```

Is this because of both Worklight instance points to same DB2? I believe this is not the case.

Help me to resolve the issue of roll back build.

Answer (score 0):

This may be happening because you are using two independent Libery profile application servers, which both point to the same database.

Because they are independent, they do not get "synced" when a Direct Update occurs.
To have this sync enabled, the application servers must be deployed as a farm of servers.

For more information on server farms, review the following documentation topic: [Defining a server farm for Worklight Server administration](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/install_config/r_config_farm_wl.html?lang=en)

Comment: Following error occured while configuring manually. 1 Detected Liberty profile runtime, getMBeansServerConnection() ENTRY localhost null,
isReady No JMX connector is configured  [project publicapp],
java.lang.Exception: No JMX connector is configured